# How to edit keyboard registry settings for keys with 3-character scan-codes?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry

I have an Apple mini-USB keyboard I am using with Windows 7. My ultimate goal is to permanently remap the F12 key to be "Delete" so I can log in with Control+Alt+Delete (apple's keyboard only has backspace).

I have identified the keyboard scan codes for the keys I want to remap using AutoHotKey.

- Delete - `153`
- F12 - `058`

I have some experience with [using the registry to remap keys](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/) such as caps to control, in this example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

The registry code for Control as per this example is `3a,00` and its scancode is `03a`. It seems you need to just remove the leading 0 in this case to remap the key.

How does this work when your scancode has a value on this leading digit? Am I suppose to just use `53` as the code?

Comment: Could you not have used something like AutoHotKey to remap it.

Comment: @DaveRook AHK only works once the script is launched, which unfortunately does not happen when I restart the machine as I have not logged in the first time yet. Trust me, if I could use AHK for this I would have :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scancodes in the registry are in *hexadecimal* (base 16), and include two bytes. The first byte is sometimes used as an escape code (`0xE0`), as for the delete key:

<kbd>Control</kbd>'s scancode is `58` or `0x003A`
<kbd>F12</kbd>'s scancode is `88` or `0x0058`
<kbd>Delete</kbd>'s scancode is escaped `83` or `0xE053`

This results in the following registry edits to make this change (note you have to increase `02,00,00,00` to `03,00,00,00` to indicate the additional key):

```
53,e0,58,00
```

What you want to do though, is get a utility called [SharpKeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/), which will provide a GUI interface to modify the registry key map. You can then compare and examine the registry key before and after to see how it changed the entry.

Comment: So to be clear - you are saying the .reg format would be `53,00` for delete and `58,00` for F12?