# How to type password with broken keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

The <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys don't work after a water spill. I have to login to backup and maybe send it for repair. I know that <kbd>Enter</kbd> can be entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>^j</kbd>, but I don't know what to do about the other keys. My password includes some of the non-working keys. How can I enter my password without having to use those keys?

Comment: And why would another keyboard be insufficient?

Comment: What OS are you using?  Windows has the onscreen keyboard . . .

Comment: 1 dont have other at hand. 2 Linux, Ubuntu. LXDE

Comment: A spare keyboard will solve more issues than you can imagine. Don't be cheap.

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers are weak. A Real Super User doesn't simply get a new keyboard when some of his keys stop working. No, that would be far too easy. He edits the registry and changes his entire keyboard configuration so he can type those letters.

This of course requires a lot more research, but you [could](https://superuser.com/questions/630964/how-to-edit-keyboard-registry-settings-for-keys-with-3-character-scan-codes) [start](https://superuser.com/questions/550679/where-to-find-windows-keyboard-scancode-registry-information) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/700110/remap-keyboard-with-scancode-map-for-disable-altctrdel).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu if you tap the Accessibility icon (a man figure) on the login screen you can choose the on-screen keyboard - it may be in one of the menus on the login screen. I've also just read that if you press `Ctrl + S` this should bring up the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and that isn't an available menu option, and CTRL + S doesn't do anything.

Comment: What ubuntu version?

Comment: The latest stable, 14.04

Comment: Have you installed a stock install? Nothing messed with such as login options?

Comment: Yeah I just installed it stock about a week ago. Nothing changed

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your login screen... There is accessibility there somewhere, I'm sure of it. Anything in top right options?

Comment: -1: in Ubuntu there is no on-screen keyboard

Comment: So what's the Universal Access Preferences all about?

Comment: Not sure if you can on the login menu (very surprised if you can't - at least - get the accessibility options) -> a cog icon? -> System Preferences -> Universal Access -> Typing Preferences -> Screen keyboard. As per: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html

Comment: I find it incredibly hard to believe Canonical wouldn't put an on screen keyboard on their product that's advertised as being usable by everyone...

Comment: Just out of curiosity I downloaded a Ubuntu 14.04 Installation (=Live CD), and voilà: Out of the box there is the "man icon" just as you described, but CTRL+S is not working: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NHsGm.png (Feel free to use my screenshot in your answer `;)`) However, it might be disabled during the installation process?!

Comment: Ah, ctrl + s is the screen reader. If your audio is on it'll read the elements on screen out loud.

Answer (score 0):

There's a virtual keyboard installed with ubuntu, try follow this guide:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/369621/how-to-get-the-onscreen-keybord-to-apper-on-login

If it's a laptop, I would recommend just get a spare standalone USB keyboard and attach to it.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard Broken?

Assuming that you are working on a computer that has a windows operating system and the mouse IS still working, the following steps can be tried to input keyboard data.

1. Click on the Windows start icon ball, open menus, click on "Switch User"
2. This screen gives a list of options in the middle of the screen, 
   however, you'll want to go to the gear icon in the LEFT lower corner 
   of the screen. Hover mouse over icon. A talking and visual menu will open.

   3. Select the option that says Keyboard Pop-up. This keyboard is designed to be used with mouse clicks, for people unable to type. If the keyboard is visually in the wrong location, click, hold, move keyboard, let-go of mouse.

Hope this helps. : )

Kaspersky Security Software also has a pop up keyboard.

Comment: They're using Ubuntu, so unfortunately this is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could type any letter with Unicode composition. However you may be limited to what you can type if you are missing any key in the hexadecimal range (0123456789abcdef).

Lets say your "g" is broken. You can still type it by:

- pressing ctrl + shift + u together and release them
- a underscored u should appear
- press 0067
- press enter -> a "g" appears

The list of codes for the letters you can find at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters (e.g. U+0067 for the "g").

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Unicode_composition